# Using QGIS to make changes to OpenStreetMap?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I want to be able to use a familiar editor (QGIS) to save building footprints to OpenStreetMap as I edit them.

I have been building a layer in QGIS and marking the polygons that need to be uploaded. I don't want to use JOSM which feels like it was written in 1985, and I don't want to re-digitize each polygon in the ID editor, because I am 62 and would die of old age before that process was completed.

There is an ArcMap tool, but it seems like there should be something in QGIS.

My data sources are license compliant (imagery and LiDAR).

Comment: Please read the [import guidelines](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Guidelines), as already mentioned by AndreJ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability to edit OSM data has been removed from QGIS a long time ago, because noone was willing to update the plugin:

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/QGIS_OSM_Plugin

JOSM is the tool to import GIS data: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Plugins/OpenData

Apart from the license question, you have to keep an eye on existing data in your working area. Make sure that existing roads and rivers don't cross your new buildings.

And regard the import and mechanical edit policies of OSM. Otherwise your changesets will be reversed.