# Exporting Shapefile polygons from ArcGIS Pro to OpenStreetMap

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, export, arcgis-pro, arcgis-editor-osm

I recently worked on a project that digitized a lot of building footprints and swimming pools with high-resolution orthorectified imagery (~4 inches resolution). The polygons are all in shapefile format with a field indicating what the feature is. The polygons were created in ArcGIS Pro. I was wondering if there might be a way for this data to be contributed to OpenStreetMap since the buildings and pools digitized are not currently on OSM.

Comment: I don't think you can bulk load as a new user. Only trusted users can do bulk imports  see Step 2 - Community Buy-in > https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Guidelines

Comment: Thank you for that information! I've been contributing to OSM for a few years now but the import process does appear to be beyond my technical expertise at the moment.

Comment: Isn't there a tool in ArcMap for uploading data to OSM? It was mentioned in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/318931/81764) about uploading to OSM from QGIS, but they didn't say what it was called.

Comment: Please read the [import guidelines](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Guidelines) and get into contact with the OSM community (e.g. via [mailing list](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mailing_lists)) before even thinking about technical details. You can't just upload all your data to OSM. This will create duplicates and/or overwrite other people's work. Also make sure the license of your data is compatible with OSM.